# Change CSS rules directly in the CSS-file

Tags: jquery, css

I want to be able to dynamically change width and height in a div that gets created by a function. The code below works but the style rules gets added directly in the HTML document, which is something I want to avoid. Instead I want the properties to be added directly to the CSS file. Is there a way to achive that?

```
...function(width, height) {

var div = $('<div/>', {
    class':  'window',
    width': width,
    height': height
}).appendTo('#content');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you need to add a class in CSS file with jquery? You can't do this directly. You can add a `<style>....</style>` tag in your HTML page's `<head>` tag with jQuery which is support you much. You can use the following methods to solve this:

```
var myStyle = { "width": "100%", "height": "90%" };
$('#content').css(myStyle);
```

OR

```
$("<style type='text/css'>#content { width: 100%; height: 90% }</style>").appendTo("head");
```

OR

```
 $.rule('#content{  width: 100%; height: 90% }').appendTo('style');
```

But remember you need to use **[plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html)** for use `$.rule` .

Comment: Yes, this should work but the thing is that I want my HTML page to be clean from CSS, ie. even in the head.

Comment: @Arif you should mention in your answer that `$.rule` is not supported by the jquery core, you have to include a plugin

Answer (score 4):

You can't write directly to the CSS files using jQuery or JavaScript, you can append in the live / rendered HTML (like you're doing above).

Why not add a class to the CSS and just switch or append that class to your DIV using jQuery?